# Extracting specific data from a string with regex and Powershell

Tags: regex, powershell

I want to extract from this string

> blocked-process-report
> process id="process435d948" taskpriority="0" logused="0" waitresource="RID: 7:1:1132932:0" waittime=
>   "3962166" ownerId="4641198" transactionname="SELECT" lasttranstarted="2011-09-13T17:21:54.950" XDES="0x80c5f060" lockMode="S" schedulerid="4" kpid="18444" status="susp
>   ended" **spid="58"** sbid="0" ecid="0"

The value that is in bold, but only the value or 58. And this value can be with different values, sometimes 80 or 1000, etc. but always > 50.

How can I do this using regex and posh?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

The quick and dirty:

```
$found = $string -match '.*spid="(\d+)".*'
if ($found) {
    $spid = $matches[1]
}
```

where `$string` is your above mentioned string.  This would match any string that has spid="somenumberhere", and make the number into a matched group, which you can extract using `$matches[1]`.

Comment: Why all the `.*` in the regex?

Comment: The `.*` will match anything before and after it on that line, its really only necessary if you used `'^.*spid="(\d+)".*$'`

Comment: You could leave them out, not sure on the performance impact of either way.  It's probably a little cleaner/faster to leave them out, didn't really think much about it.

Comment: And get all twitters usernames in a text ? http://jes.al/2009/05/how-to-parse-twitter-usernames-hashtags-and-urls-in-c-30/

Comment: `.*` should typically not be used in regular expressions, the results can be unpredictable and performance slow because it will match the entire string before backtracking to find the next pattern in the regular expression. In this particular case only `spid="(\d+)"` is required for the match.

Comment: @JonAngliss: What would then be the not "quick and dirty" way?

Answer (score 3):

Save that as, say `$string`.

Then do

```
$string -match 'spid="(\d+)"'
```

If there is a match, the value you want will be in `$matches[1]`

Comment: Be careful, even if there is NOT a match you could still end up with data in $matches[1] from a PREVIOUS regex match.

Comment: And how does one avoid that pitfall? ^^