# Find cell value begins or contains using wildcards with powershell

Tags: excel, powershell

i have a trouble findiong a value in an excel sheet.
i want to get the cell number that contains a value with a string, but i need to use wildcars.
the cell that i am searching begins with B- and i am using this code:

```
$excel = New-Object -ComObject excel.application
$destinationPath = "C:\Users\john\Desktop\wb.xlsx"
$workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Open($destinationPath)
$sheet1 = $workbook.WorkSheets.item("Sheet1")
$sheet1.activate()
$range = $sheet1.Range("A:A").EntireColumn
$s = $range.find("B-")
write-host "Range found: " $s.address().tostring()
```

this returns me the first cell that contains B- .... but i need to know the  first cell that begins with this. So i think i must use wildcards but i don't know how.

please, could anyone help me to achieve this??

thank you!! BR.

Comment: Can you give an example of  **a value with a string** in order to identify if you are looking for a [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7409133/extracting-specific-data-from-a-string-with-regex-and-powershell).

Comment: Hi Vivek !!

the word that begins with B- , after this could be any characters, like B-*

thanks!!!! ;) BR.

Comment: That should work for you - `$range.find("B-").Address()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here a working solution which is able to use regex as well:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

$excel               = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$excel.Visible       = $True
$excel.DisplayAlerts = $False 

$workbook            = $excel.Workbooks.Open( "C:\Users\john\Desktop\wb.xlsx", [System.Type]::Missing, $false ) 

$worksheet = $workbook.WorkSheets.item("Sheet1")
[void]$worksheet.activate()

$searchRange = $worksheet.Range("A:A").EntireColumn
$searchFor   = '^.*B\-.*$'

$foundCell   = $null
foreach( $cell in $searchRange.Cells ) {

    if( $cell.Value2 -match $searchFor ) {
        $foundCell = $cell
        break
    }
}

if( $foundCell ) {
   $foundCell.Value2
}

[void]$workbook.Close() 
[void]$excel.Quit() 

[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($excel) | Out-Null
```

Comment: Hi again f6a4!!
It returns this error:

Exception calling "Open" with "3" argument(s): "Old format or invalid type library. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80028018 (TYPE_E_INVDATAREAD))"

sorry for the inconveniences, Thanks, BR.

Comment: Try $excel.Workbooks.Open( "C:\Users\john\Desktop\wb.xlsx") only.

Comment: Hi again f6a4!! issue was the version of powershell console....testing in 2 machines , the second has powershell v4 , i updated to v5 and all works !! i will hope this will be helpful to others , thank you for your help !!! BR.