# How can i extract only the name from the string text

Tags: python-3.x

I am having  these texts ...

```
text1="% 4   Jérome Dekeyser + Corneille Wellens? "
text2="Matthew Sadler + Jon Speelman? 7  —"
text3="Martin Wostenholme + Frank Dancevic?  “ere"
text4="7 4   Albert Lammens + Paul de Borman?"
text5="x   Frans Gommers + Jeroen Simaeys?"
text6=" NSIe  Darryl Johansen +George Xie? "
text7="Joseph Cludts + Herman \Verbauwen? "
```

I want to extract only the names... so that i get.

```
Jérome Dekeyser + Corneille Wellens
Matthew Sadler + Jon Speelman
Martin Wostenholme + Frank Dancevic
Albert Lammens + Paul de Borman
Frans Gommers + Jeroen Simaeys
Darryl Johansen +George Xie
Joseph Cludts + Herman Verbauwen
```

The **+** sign can be ignored in the output .
This is the way what i likely want in the result ...

```
Matthew Sadler ,Jon Speelman
```

Comment: Can you define what is a name to you? Any two words with uppercase initials? Only ASCII letters? What about a name such as ``Armin van Grünwald``?

Comment: Any two letter with uppercase initials can be preferred .. But if 3 letter name  as you said `Armin van Grünwald` can be solved...it will be a great pleasure.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extracting specific data from a string with regex and Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7409133/extracting-specific-data-from-a-string-with-regex-and-powershell)

Comment: Consider this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7409133/extracting-specific-data-from-a-string-with-regex-and-powershell). The regex can look something like this `'\b\w+ \w+\b'`.

Comment: Regex is the right tool for this and its tricky to give you one exact as its too abstract, because you have special characters like é. you need to see what you want to match exactly!!!

Comment: +Alex_P Well Alex `\b\w+ \w+\b` This is working to much extent...but its not working for 3 words name , Like `Martin de Vries`

Comment: use `regex` as it supports `\p` thus something like: `regex.sub(r'[\d\p{P}]','',text7)` should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regular expression can likely be refined, but it works for all you examples, including Armin van Grünwald.

```
import re as regex

text1="% 4   Jérome Dekeyser + Corneille Wellens? "

extract_names = regex.findall(r'\b(?!\d)\w+\s\w+\s\w+\b|\b(?!\d)\w+\s\w+\b', text1)

print (extract_names)
# outputs 
['Jérome Dekeyser', 'Corneille Wellens']

print (', '.join(extract_names))
# outputs 
Jérome Dekeyser, Corneille Wellens
```